# Azure IIS Custom Logging

Tags: azure, iis, iis-8

I am currently trying to add a custom field to my iis log file in order to capture a guid that identifies the user making each request in our system. Making the following change works on my local machine due to the fact that I am running IIS 10.

```
<logFile logExtFileFlags="Date, Time, ClientIP, UserName, ServerIP, Method, UriStem, UriQuery, HttpStatus, Win32Status, TimeTaken, ServerPort, UserAgent, Referer, HttpSubStatus" logFormat="W3C" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles">
     <customFields>
          <clear />
          <add logFieldName="SubjectId" sourceName="SubjectId" sourceType="RequestHeader" />
     </customFields>
</logFile>
```

Because our site is hosted on Microsoft Azure, which is running IIS 8.0, I am unable to make this change on our production environment. Per Microsoft's site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/logfile/customfields/) it appears iis custom field logging is not possible until IIS 8.5.

Is there any way to upgrade the version of IIS in Azure to 8.5+ or any alternative way to capture this data with iis logging?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please tell me which version of the VM you have used in the Azure? As far as I know, we couldn't install different IIS version in one server.

Comment: The VM I am using is of type "Virtual Machine (classic)".